# Angular 2 / SystemJS not using default extension for package

Tags: angular, systemjs

This is what I have:

```
 var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'angular2-jwt':               'node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt'
  };

  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-jwt':               { defaultExtension: "js" }
  };
```

The browser complains that it cannot find the file "angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt". It seems as if it is not using the default extension ".js"

Adding this extension manually like :

```
var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'angular2-jwt':               'node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js'
  };
```

solves the problem, but leaves me dumbfounded (which I only like when brought upon me by a woman)

Any hints?

Comment: The only hint i can give is (which isn't worth an answer) is that you're not the only one with this problem: https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/61 and some other issues / code samples i found have that `.js` added at the end as well. So probably it's not a `systemjs` issue.